# Search List content using Linq

Tags: .net, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have List of object which contains values in following pattern

```
2$FirstLevel+HRMS

2#40#56$SecondLevelOperation+Add

2#60$SecondLevel+dffddfdf
```

Using Linq i want to select the record which contains '2' value in it and does not contain 'Operation' word. that means it should select 1st and 3rd value only not the second value. how to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you indicate you have a *List of objects*, I do not assume it is a `List<string>` (or another enumerable of strings). If it is, omit the `OfType<string>`, as it is superfluous. Beyond that, the following code should get you started.

```
var results = list.OfType<string>().Where(item => item.Contains("2") && !item.Contains("Operation"));
```

If any of the items in the list could be null, you would want to add the appropriate null checking (or handling) to accommodate those entries.